# How to convert a Python list into a dictionary with "default" key values?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a list of objects

```
list = ['abc', 'dog', 'cat', 'bird',.....]
```

I am currently outputting this list as a text file. I would like to transform this into a dictionary, such that the "key values" are indices beginning at zero.

```
dict = {0: 'abc', 1: 'dog', 2: 'cat', 3: 'bird', ...}
```

How does one do this?

Comment: What's the end game here?  After it's in the text file will you slurp it back in to another program?  Will you use it as a dictionary in the new program?  Or will you eventually reassemble it into a list?

Comment: I have to ask -- What is the purpose of having a dictionary whose key values are integers starting at 0 and increasing sequentially?  Why not just keep using a list?  What do you gain from a dict in this case?

Comment: @mgilson:  I was going to ask that as well, but I imagine it has something to do with how the OP is using it after it's dumped to file.  So I asked about that.  But it's a legitimate question, why make a pretend list when you can have a real one.  (I think we have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way would be using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and just making it a dict.

```
my_list = ['abc', 'dog', 'cat', 'bird', ...]
my_dict = dict(enumerate(my_list))
```

`enumerate` takes a list and makes the list and makes a new list with tuples of `(count, value)`. E.g.: `enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c'])` -> (An enumerate object for) `((0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'))`

Comment: You will shadow the built-in `list` object, use another variable name

Comment: @IronFist Fixed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) built-in method:

```
>>> lst = ['abc', 'dog', 'cat', 'bird']
>>> 
>>> d1 = dict(enumerate(lst))
>>> d1
{0: 'abc', 1: 'dog', 2: 'cat', 3: 'bird'}
```

Comment: Up for using `lst` as var name

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
>>> a = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> dict(zip(range(len(a)), a))
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
>>>
```